# Agregar Iframe en un DIV

Tags: html

Estimados, estoy generando un `html` y deseo agregar una imagen que se encuentra en una ruta de wordpress en un `iframe` dentro de mi página.

```
<div class="box-img-login">
    <iframe width="288px" height="214px" src="<portalWebUtils:link key="link.imagen.banner.login"/>" alt="Banner"></iframe>
</div>
```

Pero el `div` se muestra con `scroll` horizontal y vertical, he probado algunos atributos del `iframe` pero no he logrado quitar los `scroll`. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Que quieres que el iframe sea igual de grande que el div?

Comment: Claro, la idea es dejar el iframe administrable (es una imagen), que rellene el espacio completo que está destinado en el div @Error404

Comment: El problema son los estilos que vienen del link al que enlazas el iframe. Puedes observar que llega una clase con `.sidebarWrap` si inspeccionas el elemento la cual te está haciendo que el iframe ocupe un 30% de la anchura del div.

Comment: Hola @Stevn he eliminado mi respuesta. Agrega el comentario que indicaste en mi respuesta (el que te solucionó la pregunta) como una respuesta a tu propia pregunta. De esta manera, la gente que venga posteriormente, podrá ver tu respuesta y les podrá ser útil al verlo de una manera mucho más fácil. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estimados las respuesta para la consulta realizada es la siguiente.

```
          <div class="box-img-login">
            <iframe width="288px" height="214px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="<portalWebUtils:link key="link.imagen.banner.login"/>" alt="Banner"></iframe>
          </div>
```

Saludos.